# Dalvik registers higher than 256

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik, vm-implementation

Dalvik documentation says that "some instructions have variants that allow for much larger register counts, including a pair of catch-all move instructions that can address registers in the range v0 – v65535."
But I can't see such move instructions in the table of bytecodes.
So what is it about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `move/16`, `move-wide/16`,  etc. instructions use 16 bits to store both the source and destination register, so they can reference up to v65535. There's also the `move-*/from16` variants, which have a 16 bit source register and an 8 bit destination register.